# i have following code for jframe.i want to add a jdialog whose parent is the current jframe.pls suggest

Tags: java, swing

the code i have used is this.i want the new jDialog to be subclass of the ManagerScreen Frame.here using 'this' id not helping as i am inside inner class.

```
class ManagerScreen extends JFrame {
...

void createGui() {
JButton btncreateacc = new JButton("Create Account");
btncreateacc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            new JDialog(ManagerScreen) ;


        }
    });
}
}
```

however it gives error . pls suggest how it can be done?

Comment: _i want the new jDialog to be subclass of the ManagerScreen Frame_ that's not possible. Take a step back and  learn some basics about a) inheritance b) usage. Knowing the technical terms is _important_

Answer (score 3):

Use `ManagerScreen.this`

```
new JDialog(ManagerScreen.this, "Dialog Title", true);
```

using `this` buy itself, is actually pointing to the `ActionListener` class

See [JDialog Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) for more constructors.

---

> *"i want the new jDialog to be subclass of the ManagerScreen Frame"*

Also, not the above does not make, the `JDialog` a sublcass of the `JFrame` class but instead, makes the `JFrame` the *owner* of the `JDialog`